# I cannot connect the aws instance with ssh

Tags: amazon-ec2

I created a aws EC2 instance, but I cannot access it.
SSH timed out and ping doesn't reach it.
All settings include security group, VPC are default.
I cannot find what is wrong.
Would someone tell me where I should check?

Comment: If you want someone to help, you need to provide as much information as possible. Your post has very little info. Start with the output of `ssh -v ....`

Answer (score 0):

I found I had tried to connect EC2 instances from my company's VPN.
After disconnecting the VPN, I could logged in the instances

Answer (score 0):

Please try EC2 Instance Connect,  It worked for me

- In your Instances pages click the **Connect** button,
- Choose the Connection Method as **EC2 Instance Connect**
- Use the same  Username = **ec2-user**
- Click **Connect** button
  Here it is the promt screen you can continue your job. :)

you may need to do the below first, if it didn' start.

In the **IAM console**, choose **Policies**, **Create Policy**.
On the **Create Policy** page, choose **JSON** and  copy past the below section. ( If needed replace $REGION and $ACCOUNTID with your own values)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2-instance-connect:SendSSHPublicKey"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:$REGION:$ACCOUNTID:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:osuser": "ec2-user"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

(Not: This is not an exact solution but if your job is urgent,  this is the  easiest, safe and alternative way to do)
I think the main problem comes from the Identity and Access Managemet (IAM) Security section, users' roles  related.

---

I had the same problem : I wanted to connect AWS instance, I copied the key into the Desktop, when I put the SSH link into  ANACONDA promt(Anaconda3) , it gave the message:

**.ssh/config line 9: garbage at end of line; "Drive\DATA".**

I tried from CMD,or powershell, id didn't change.
I re install a new Instance, didn't change.
I change the internet line to a different network, it didn't change.

---

For mor information:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-using-amazon-ec2-instance-connect-for-ssh-access-to-your-ec2-instances/